# I keep receiving this exception - Exception has occurred. EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1b8c50bb0)

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, c-strings, strcat

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char first[] = "This is the first part of";
    char second[] = "the full string, this being the second half\n.";
    char buffer[70];
    strcpy(buffer,first);
    strcat(buffer,second);
    puts(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

I am receiving the error on strcat function, please assist
[image]

Comment: From the documentation: [The strcat() function appends the src string to the dest string, overwriting the terminating null byte ('\0') at the end of dest, and then adds a terminating null byte.](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcat.3.html). Your two strings have 25 and 45 characters. So where do you suppose this terminating null byte is going to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the size of the array `buffer` is not large enough to contain the concatenated strings.

Declare it at least like

```
char first[] = "This is the first part of";
char second[] = "the full string, this being the second half\n.";
char buffer[sizeof( first ) + sizeof( second ) - 1];
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution worked. You forgot the ; at the end thoooo.

Comment: your the best Vlad

Comment: @Dareus If the problem is resolved then close the question selecting the best answer and your reputation will be increased.